# Termination of Moore's algorithm to minimize deterministic automata

Tags: algorithms, automata

I use Moore's algorithm to minimize DFA as concluded below.

1. We start with the complete graph with vertices `Q` and edges `E = { {p, q} | p = q ∈ Q }`
2. We mark all edges `{p, q} ∈ E` with `p ∈ F` and `q ∈ F`
3. As long as there exist marked edges in `E`, we repeat the following procedure. We choose some marked edge `{p , q } ∈ E`. Then we mark all unmarked edges `{p, q} ∈ E` with `{p , q } = {p · a, q · a}` for some `a ∈ Σ`. Afterwards we remove the edge `{p , q }` from `E`.
4. All marked edges are eventually removed.

Then I guess a new minimal automata is obtained by joining the states linked by the remaining unmarked edges. Is it true?

If so, what about this case?

```
States: {1, 2, 3}
Alphabet: {a, b}
Start: 1
Final: {3}
Transition: {(1, a, 2), (2, b, 3)}
```

By Moore's algorithm, at the end of loop we will have one unmarked edge between state `1` and `2`. 
As my guess above, the next step is joining both states.
But the result doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're guessing. An algorithm is, by definition, a description of _exactly_ what needs to be done. If you want to know what an algorithm does, read the algorithm.

Comment: This isn't Moore's algorithm, so it's no surprise that your result doesn't make sense. Go back to your notes and *carefully* compare the algorithm with what you've written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most minimization algorithms assume automata to be **complete** s.t. for every state `p` and alphabet `a`, there is a transition where `(p, a, q)`. Hence, for the case, we need to add one more state as a sink state.
The DFA becomes:

```
States: {1, 2, 3, 4}
Alphabet: {a, b}
Start : 1
Final : {3}
Transition : 
{(1, a, 2), (1, b, 4), (2, a, 4), (2, b, 3), (3, a, 4), (3, b, 4), 
(4, a, 4), (4, b, 4)}
```

By Moore's algorithm:

Picking `edge(3,4)` causes we mark `edge(2,1)` and `edge(2,4)` by `b`-transition.

Picking `edge(2,4)` causes we mark `edge(1,4)` by `a`-transition.

Now we don't have any unmarked edges left. Hence, no states has to be joined.